# HBase: /hbase/meta-region-server node does not exist

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, cloudera, apache-zookeeper

I have installed cloudera and hdfs, mapreduce, zookeper, hbase on it. 4 nodes with these services (3 zookeeper). All are installed by cloudera wizard and have no configuration issues in cloudera.
On connect from java I have got an error:

> 9:32:23.020 [main-SendThread()] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn
>   - Opening socket connection to server /172.20.7.6:2181 09:32:23.020 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper -
>   Process identifier=hconnection-0x301abf87 connecting to ZooKeeper
>   ensemble=172.20.7.6:2181 09:32:23.028
>   [main-SendThread(cloudera2.pjk-tvs...:2181)] INFO 
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to
>   cloudera2.pjk-tvs.../172.20.7.6:2181, initiating
>   session 09:32:23.029
>   [main-SendThread(cloudera2.pjk-tvs...net:2181)] DEBUG
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment request sent
>   on cloudera2.pjk-tvs.../172.20.7.6:2181
>   09:32:23.035
>   [main-SendThread(cloudera2.pjk-tvs...:2181)] INFO 
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on
>   server cloudera2.pjk-tvs.../172.20.7.6:2181,
>   sessionid = 0x2423aeb0f790ff2, negotiated timeout = 60000 09:32:23.037
>   [main-EventThread] DEBUG
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher -
>   hconnection-0x301abf87 Received ZooKeeper Event, type=None,
>   state=SyncConnected, path=null 09:32:23.040 [main-EventThread] DEBUG
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher -
>   hconnection-0x301abf87-0x2423aeb0f790ff2 connected 09:32:23.041
>   [main-SendThread(cloudera2.pjk-tvs...:2181)] DEBUG
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply
>   sessionid:0x2423aeb0f790ff2, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null
>   finished:false header:: 1,3  replyHeader:: 1,8589982838,0  request::
>   '/hbase/hbaseid,F  response::
>   s{16,8589934615,1383919470521,1383967999584,4,0,0,0,85,0,16}
>   09:32:23.044
>   [main-SendThread(cloudera2....:2181)] DEBUG
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply
>   sessionid:0x2423aeb0f790ff2, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null
>   finished:false header:: 2,4  replyHeader:: 2,8589982838,0  request::
>   '/hbase/hbaseid,F  response::
>   ffffffff0002c3131363140636c6f7564657261312e706a6b2d7476732e633467642e6772696464796e616d6963732e6e657465633932386436332d316334652d346336652d616238392d646237343239646231336638,s{16,8589934615,1383919470521,1383967999584,4,0,0,0,85,0,16}
>   09:32:23.100 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient -
>   Codec=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.codec.KeyValueCodec@11fb24d3,
>   compressor=null, tcpKeepAlive=true, tcpNoDelay=true,
>   maxIdleTime=10000, maxRetries=0, fallbackAllowed=false, ping
>   interval=60000ms, bind address=null 09:32:23.109
>   [main-SendThread(cloudera2.pjk-tvs...:2181)] DEBUG
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply
>   sessionid:0x2423aeb0f790ff2, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null
>   finished:false header:: 3,4  replyHeader:: 3,8589982838,-101 
>   request:: '/hbase/meta-region-server,F  response:: 09:32:23.116 [main]
>   DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil -
>   hconnection-0x301abf87-0x2423aeb0f790ff2 Unable to get data of znode
>   /hbase/meta-region-server because node does not exist (not an error)
>   09:32:23.317
>   [main-SendThread(cloudera2.pjk-tvs...:2181)] DEBUG
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply
>   sessionid:0x2423aeb0f790ff2, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null
>   finished:false header:: 4,4  replyHeader:: 4,8589982838,-101 
>   request:: '/hbase/meta-region-server,F  response:: 09:32:23.318 [main]
>   DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil -
>   hconnection-0x301abf87-0x2423aeb0f790ff2 Unable to get data of znode
>   /hbase/meta-region-server because node does not exist (not an error)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had tryied to connect to HBase 0.94 by client 0.96.
And acording to https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/10/what-are-hbase-znodes/
znode /hbase/root-region-server is replaced in 0.96 by /hbase/meta-region-server, that the java client wasn't able to find.

Comment: How did you fixed you issue ?

Comment: What do mean by " /hbase/meta-region-server is replaced in 0.96 by /hbase/meta-region-server, that the java client wasn't able to find " isn't the /hbase/meta-region-server the same ?

Comment: Sorry, "root-region-server" was replaced by meta-region-server. Solution is just use client version appropriated to server version.

Comment: Hi, I have hbase server version as 0.98.4-hadoop2 what should be the client version? I am encountering the error " Unable to get data of znode /hbase/root-region-server because node does not exist (not an error)" for using hbase-client-0.98.4-hadoop2 with hbase-0.98.4-hadoop2

Comment: I can't emphasize enough how important syncing versions is for HBase. Even the version compatibility matrix in the docs isn't strict enough with Hadoop versions.