# HBase fails with org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException region is not online

Tags: asynchronous, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have an asynchronous application that saves data to HBase using [async-hbase-client.](https://github.com/jurmous/async-hbase-client)

My HBase version is: 1.0.0-cdh5.6.0
My async HBase client version is: 0.9.0

The application ran fine for a while (~4 or 5 days) but during the weekend it started failing with the following exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region pageviews,,1463568860289.298bb29bbd148a0a62ec90885ef8d027. is not online on //some address here
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:2786)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getRegion(RSRpcServices.java:922)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.mutate(RSRpcServices.java:1965)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2034)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What I did:

- I verified that HBase is indeed functioning by going into the HBase shell and playing with some tables there which worked fine
- I logged into the zookeeper shell by running `./hbase zkcli` and then running: `rmr /hbase/root-region-server` - I did this according to this link: http://rogueleaderr.com/post/32963921889/hbase-error-region-is-not-online-root-0. This did not work with the following error: `Node does not exist: /hbase/root-region-server`. I tried resolving this problem and encountered this solution suggestion: [HBase: /hbase/meta-region-server node does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903622/hbase-hbase-meta-region-server-node-does-not-exist). So instead I ran: `rmr /hbase/meta-region-server` which didn't do anything (at least it didn't write anything)
- I tried looking for other solutions, some suggested it has something to do with incompatible HBase versions which might sound right but it did work for several days without any issues so I'm wondering what exactly is the problem

If anyone has any ideas on what exactly is the problem here I'll appreciate it. Currently I'm kind of in the dark here

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to fix this ? below answer helped ?

Comment: I just saw the answer :) so I didn't have time to check it out. I'll obviously update after I try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like one particular table and its region got corrupted(you are able to access other tables from hbase shell as you described), please try [hbase hbck](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/hbck.in.depth.html) on specific table name which may fix this

**[Other Option](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/8757/phoenix-local-indexes.html) :** 
you could solve this by increasing number of threads required to open the regions so that meta regions can be assigned even threads for local index table is still waiting to remove the deadlock.

```
<property> <name>hbase.regionserver.executor.openregion.threads</name> <value>100</value> </property>
```

Comment: Hi, we had to restart our service so the problem is not yet reproducible. I did check the hbck command which seems like a good fit for my previous issue. I will let it run for 2 or 3 days and see if it occurs again and if it does I'll try and solve it using one of your suggestions. Thanks for your answer! I'll update you soon

Comment: I will do that as soon as I find out if it does solve my issue

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't respond earlier but I kind of had to leave this abruptly because of more urgent tasks. Anyway the hbck command helped
Thanks!

Comment: I encounter this Error when I reinstall Hbase cluster, It is solved by deleting the previous data, including the following three parts。1. `/hbase` node in zookeeper. 
   2.hdfs directory, The configuration item of this path in the previous cluster configuration file `hbase-site.xml` is `hbase.rootdir` . If the configuration value of the current cluster is different from that of the previous cluster, don't worry.   3. Delete the local directory created by HBase on each node. The configuration item in the configuration file `hbase-site.xml` is `hbase.tmp.dir`.